Deitmar notation for a distribution as an integral
I am having trouble understanding notation in Chapter 4 of Anton Deitmar's A First Course in Harmonic Analysis. Deitmar defines a distribution to be a linear functional from smooth functions with compact support to $\mathbb{C}$ (the domain is given a slightly non-standard topology in his book, but I think that is not relevant to this question). He then says:

A distribution $T$ in general is not a function, so it does not make sense to write $T(x)$, but nevertheless, it is convenient to write $$T(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty T(x) f(x)\ dx.$$ For instance, the distribution $T(x - a), a \in \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty T(x - a)f(x)\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty T(x) f(x + a)\ dx.$$ So $T(x - a)$ applied to $f$ equals $T$ applied to $x \mapsto f(x + a)$. For example, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x - a)f(x)\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)f(x + a)\ dx = f(a).$$

$\delta$ was defined on the previous page as the delta distribution: $\delta(f) = f(0)$.
I know that there is some abuse of notation in here that is losing me, but I'm not sure where. I don't understand what $T(f)$ is defining since I can't actually take the integral on the right hand side, since, as Deitmar points out, $T(x)$ is not defined. I thought perhaps that $T(x)$ was suppose to represent the distribution $T$ applied to the identity function on $\mathbb{R}$, but this doesn't seem to give the correct result.
So I am lost as to what this $T(f)$ means. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The equation$$T(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty T(x) f(x)\ dx$$does not define $T(f)$, but instead the RHS is defined to be equal to the LHS.

Yes this is one of the points I was missing, thanks!

The way I see it is the following: $T(f)$ itself (without the integral) makes perfect sense. It is just the value of $T$ when I plug in the function $f$.
Now even though it is not always possible to write $T(f)$ as an integral of the form $\int h(x) f(x) dx$, this is exactly the structure which is prototypical and which we should have in mind. I believe that Deitmar therefore chooses to write $T(f)= \int T(x) f(x) dx$ as a symbolic notation. The example you have in your question on how to interpret "$T(x-a)$" is then motivated by exactly that: If $T$ was representable as an integral of some function times $f$, then it would transform like this (applying the distribution to $f(x+a)$. This is also the motivation on how to define $T'(f)$, so a derivative of $T$. If $T$ was representable by a function $h$, then $T'$ should act like $h'$, so by integration by parts we have
$$T'(f)= \int h'(x) f(x) dx = -\int h(x) f'(x)dx,$$
so we define $T'(f)= -T(f')$, where the right hand side makes sense because it is just $T$ applied to some other function.
The takeaway is that we always pretend that the distribution works like an integral to understand how it should transform under certain things.

At the risk of saying something completely stupid, I can try to explain this a bit.
Let's take a nice compactly-supported smooth function $g$. We can "integrate against $g$" to define a linear operation on things in $L^2$ this:
$$
G(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x) ~dx.
$$
If you give me a function $g$, I can build an associated distribution $G$.
Is that clear? One might even say that most distributions look like this -- they can be described as "integration against some nice function." And when you do that, you have all the tools of calculus (like substitution, or integration by parts, or ...) to work with.
Of course, the "interesting" distributions like $\delta$ do not arise from integration against some function. But if we pretend that they do, and use all those tools of calculus, it turns out (or so I'm told) that we get valid results even from this fictional approach.
Now comes the ugly part: I made a clear distinction between my compactly-supported smooth function $g$ and the associated distribution $G$. But apparently your author (and maybe others in this field) prefers to use the same name for the two -- if you have a distribution named $Q$, then it's either "integration against some nice function which we're also going to call $Q$", or "we're going to pretend it's defined by integration against some nice function, which we're also going to call $Q$."
I think that's what's going on in this paragraph.
